# slide div to center using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div in left side, I want once click on div slide (move) it to center,

My code:

```
$('#operator_' + opids[i]).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

but it does not work.

can anyone give me jquery code to achieve this?

Comment: Which error return? is correct the param opids[i]? show your complete code

Comment: complete code:  var opids = allOpid.split(",");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < opids.length; i++){   
           $('#operator_' + opids[i]).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  
        }

Comment: I need jquery code slide div from left to center.

Comment: that can't be the complete code, the variable allOpid isn't defined. And why is this being done in a loop? whats the error messages? define "but it does not work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `animate()`:

```
$('#operator_' + opids[i]).animate({marginLeft: "+=200px"}, "slow");
```

This will make the object identified by `$('#operator_' + opids[i])` move to the right (because the leftMargin is increased) by 200px. The 2nd parameter is the speed. The first parameter can take any CSS values.

[More info about jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).